# Replace multiple values in file loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to build a quick and dirty static site generator for myself.

Let's say I have this `test.html` file:

```
{title}
{downloadpath}
```

This is my `current.json` where I get the values i want to replace:

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "album" : [{
        "title": "Test EP",
        "albumid": 1234,
        "path": "test.zip"
     }]
}
```

My replacement function looks like this:

```
    // Iterate through JSON object and replace
    function iterate(obj) {
        for (var property in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                if (typeof obj[property] == "object")
                    iterate(obj[property]);
                else
                console.log("replace {" + property + "} with " + obj[property] )
                htmldata.replace(/\{property\}/g, obj[property]);
            }
        }
    }
    iterate(json)
    var result = htmldata

    console.log(result)

    // Write new HTML
    fs.writeFile("test-" + json.id + ".html", result, 'utf8', function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

and if I run it it works like this:

```
replace {id} with 123
replace {title} with Test EP
replace {albumid} with 1234
replace {path} with test.zip
{title}
{path}
```

and you can see the problem right there. I think it's always replacing the edited file with the input file so I don't see any changes. I can't figure it out and if someone could point me in the right direction I'd be grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: you can simply work with something like underscore's `_.template` function and skip the self-rolling-template-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not using braces around your `if` statements will lead to subtle bugs!

You want:

```
if (typeof obj[property] == "object") {
    iterate(obj[property]);
} else {
    console.log("replace {" + property + "} with " + obj[property] )
    htmldata.replace(/\{property\}/g, obj[property]);
}
```

Otherwise the `replace` will run *every time* regardless of the condition on the `if`.

Second thing: your regex tries to match the literal string `"{property}"`. Instead, try this:

```
htmldata.replace(new RegExp("{" + property + "}", "g"), obj[property]);
```

Third thing: you're not assigning the result of the `replace` *back* to `htmldata`. So you need to do this:

```
htmldata = htmldata.replace(new RegExp("{" + property + "}", "g"), obj[property]);
```

Comment: the result of `htmldata.replace()` needs to be reassigned as well?

Comment: @pero Ah yes, it does. I should write out the whole line - I just wrote the replace part. Editing now!

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working perfectly now, I was literally looking at this code for hours now.